# Oracle Apex: how to not display "Stay on page"-message?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I've got an apex **report page** where the user can filter the results with a custom LOV-value. Works ok.

Only thing is: if the user changes the lov-value and subsequently leaves the page, a message gets displayed that unsaved data might be lost and if the user wants to stay on the page instead. As the page is only a report and no data are saved that's somehow pointless.

Is there a way to suppress this message by means of java-script or whatever?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for JavaScript - there is a declarative setting, either at item level or page level.

Look for 'Warn on Unsaved Changes'.

[image: item level setting]